# How does this macro dispatcher work?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I saw this mechanism to simulate macro overloading recently [here](http://efesx.com/2010/08/31/overloading-macros/) .

This is the code used for dispatching:

```
#define macro_dispatcher(func, ...) \
             macro_dispatcher_(func, VA_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))
#define macro_dispatcher_(func, nargs) \
            macro_dispatcher__(func, nargs)
#define macro_dispatcher__(func, nargs) \
            func ## nargs
```

I don't understand how this works. Why does it need the third macro `macro_dispatcher__` to concatenate the arguments? I have tried to eliminate the third macro and replace it with the second one, resulting this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "va_numargs.h"

 #define macro_dispatcher(func, ...) \
      macro_dispatcher_(func, __VA_NUM_ARGS__(__VA_ARGS__))

 #define macro_dispatcher_(func, nargs) \
     func ## nargs

 #define max(...) macro_dispatcher(max, __VA_ARGS__) \
      (__VA_ARGS__)                                    

 #define max1(a) a                                    
 #define max2(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

 int main()                                
 {                                         
     max(1);

     max(1, 2);

     return 0; 
 }
```

`va_numargs.h`:

```
  #ifndef _VA_NARG_H
  #define _VA_NARG_H

  #define __VA_NUM_ARGS__(...) \
               PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__,PP_RSEQ_N())
  #define PP_NARG_(...) \
               PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
  #define PP_ARG_N( \
                    _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10, \
                   _11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20, \
                   _21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30, \
                   _31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40, \
                   _41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50, \
                   _51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60, \
                   _61,_62,_63,N,...) N
  #define PP_RSEQ_N() \
               63,62,61,60,                   \
           59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50, \
           49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40, \
           39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30, \
           29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20, \
           19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10, \
           9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0

  #endif
```

Which evaluates to this:

```
int main()
{
     max__VA_NUM_ARGS__(1) (1);

     max__VA_NUM_ARGS__(1, 2) (1, 2);

     return 0;
}
```

What is happening here? Why isn't `__VA_NUM_ARGS__(__VA_ARGS__)` replaced with the acutal number of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra step is needed because the token concatenation operator (`##`) suppresses macro expansion of its operands. Here's a simple example that demonstrates the problem:

```
#define macro macro_expansion
#define concat(x, y) x ## y

concat(macro, macro)
```

You might expect the above to produce `macro_expansionmacro_expansion`, but what you get instead is `macromacro`. While expanding the right-hand side of `concat()`, the preprocessor notices that `x` and `y` (which are set to `macro` here) are used as operands to `##`, and so does not expand them further.

To work around this, we can add another step:

```
#define macro macro_expansion
#define concat(x, y) concat_(x, y)
#define concat_(x, y) x ## y

concat(macro, macro)
```

Now `x` and `y` are no longer operands of '##' in the right-hand side of `concat()`, and are therefore expanded. This means that we get `concat_(macro_expansion, macro_expansion)`, which in turn expands to `macro_expansionmacro_expansion`.

The stringification operator (`#`) also suppresses macro expansion by the way.

Here's the relevant part of the C11 spec. (section 6.10.3.1):

> A parameter in the replacement list, *unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token* (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded.